# django-dajaxice overriding XMLHttpRequest

Tags: javascript, python, ajax, django

We are using Django 1.4 with django-dajaxice. I recently found out that django-dajaxice overrides the default XMLHttpRequest object [ http://django-dajaxice.readthedocs.org/en/latest/ ]. It's a problem since we want to use https://github.com/tadruj/s3upload-coffee-javascript and it calls the method overrideMimeType of the object XMLHttpRequest(), which is undefined. I would like to know if it's possible to use django-dajaxice without overriding the default XMLHttpRequest class, or do we have not to use django-dajaxice at all? I think it's strange that a JavaScript plugin overrides a default object such as XMLHttpRequest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution - look here: https://github.com/jorgebastida/django-dajaxice/blob/master/dajaxice/templates/dajaxice/dajaxice.core.js There is a variable `DAJAXICE_XMLHTTPREQUEST_JS_IMPORT`. If we set it to False in settings then django-dajaxice will not override XMLHttpRequest.

```
DAJAXICE_XMLHTTPREQUEST_JS_IMPORT = False
```